# Accessing XML Data Set in Bursting Query for BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, report, bi-publisher

I am currently creating a data model in BI Publisher which has an XML file for its data set. I am however unfamiliar on how to access its contents for the Bursting Query.

Here is a sample of my XML file:

```
<records>
    <customer>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>john</name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>456</id>
        <name>jane</name>
    </customer>
</records>
```

I am familiar on how to burst to file, email, etc... The problem is on how to query the XML file for the Bursting Query.

Comment: Have you succeeded in running the report, using the XML file as data source, without bursting?

Comment: You say you are familiar with bursting, yet your comments indicate that you are not.  When bursting you do not query the XML file at all.  You need to tell the bursting control file which node to burst on.  Google for ```bursting control file``` - there is a slew of documentation out there.  Plenty to get you going on your own.